# Can static generic function interfere with each other (c#)?

Tags: c#, static

Suppose there is a static extension function for caching the results like this:

```
public static Func<T, R> Memoize<T, R>(this Func<T, R> func)
{
    var cache = new Dictionary<T, R>();
    R result = default(R);
    return x => cache.TryGetValue(x, out result) ? result : cache[x] = func(x);
}
```

If in the main method I declare

```
Func<int, int> func1;
func1 = (x) => x + 1;      // one method with <int, int>
func1 = func1.Memoize();

Func<int, long> func2;
func2 = (x) => x - 1;      // other method with <int, long>
func2 = func2.Memoize();
```

they will work fine. But what if I declare both delegates with identical type signature? Will they corrupt the results for each other if they are called?

Comment: This is an extension method so while technically it is a static mehod, you are using an instance (called `func` in this case) so no, they should not collide.

Comment: Thanks. They also do not collide even if non-extension. I suppose they would if the dictionary was separate static field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you think the type signatures would have any impact on your `Memoize` function.  Each invocation of `Memoize` instantiates its own dictionary.  Therefore `func1` and `func2` would operate independenty of one another regardless of the types involved.

To clarify a bit further, the function you return from `Memoize` captures the dictionary in a closure and thus has a reference to the instance created on the first line.  Since you call `Memoize` twice, there are two separate dictionaries in play.

Comment: I was under the impression that static methods are created once on first calling, so if one Memoize<int, int> was present the program would use it if called from another delegate.

Comment: Static methods are not "created" -- they are just methods that do not require an instance of the surrounding class to operate (i.e. they have no access to `this`).  However, each invocation of a static method operates independently -- you are creating a dictionary upon each invocation, so each function returned has its own unique copy.

Comment: Yes, I meant static instances, not methods.

Comment: There is no such thing as "static instances" in C#.  What you have is a static method.